# How can i get rid of the line under the text of a button

Tags: html, css

I have this one button which has some sort of line under it.

[image]
it's small and blue but it annoys me.

```css
#p {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  color: #588b42;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1a1a19;
}

#p:hover,
#p:visited,
#p:link,
#p:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank"><button id="p">Portfolio</button></a>
```

I tried to set text-decoration to none, both in the normal style for the button and in every single pseudo-class, but it has not done anything

This is what i've tried:

```
#p{text-decoration: none;}

#p:hover, #p:visited, #p:link, #p:active {text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] and see [ask] please

Comment: Please show some code. We can't help you improve or fix code that we can't see

Comment: we are interested in the current code, not the code you tested. if necessary, use your browser's code inspector!

Comment: You have your `button` inside an `a`. The `a` has `text-decoration: underline`, as normal. You need to set it on the `a`, not the `button`.

Comment: But _please_ **DO NOT** nest interactive elements. It is invalid HTML and bad for a11y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line comes from the anchor, not the button, and all your selectors are targeting the button with the ID of `p`. So you need `a{text-decoration: none;}`.

But note that a button in an anchor is invalid HTML

Comment: Preferably, put the ID on the anchor instead of the button and use that, instead of applying that to _all_ anchors on the page.